# symfony console command 113 exit code

Tags: symfony, console, command

hey I have a command in symfony , once I run it on production the command exit with 113 code , the symfony version is 3.4 , and I noticed that when I set maintenance to true that happen otherwise it works fine

Comment: Check if you have some dump in the command

Comment: no nothing , but I found out what was happening , once I set maintenance to true in parameters.yml file for some unknown reasons the command did not work

Answer (score 1):

If anyone comes across this in the future: In my case there was a listener in the application that disabled the command (depending on arbitrary conditions). If you launch your command in verbose mode `-vvv` and see a `113` response, you might be in this situation and want to look for `->disableCommand()` in your code.

More about this here: https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/components/console/events.html#disable-commands-inside-listeners